# ADODB Excel/Access SQL Insert rounding off decimals: any idea why or how to fix?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

Good morning,

I'm currently working on a project where we need to export some Excel data to Access via VBA; I'm doing the VBA in Excel, as we have a macro already that does all our formatting and other stuff.  The macro works fine (the data is imported successfully) but with one problem: for some reason, some unknown bug (could be either on the Excel, Access, SQL or ADODB side) is rounding all decimal numbers to whole numbers ("ints").  I didn't use any kind of rounding functions in my VBA or SQL code (see below), and the columns in Access have "Number" data types (and "General Number" format) with two decimal places, so I have no idea why it's rounding.  Maybe something in the ADODB object (which I've only learned to use recently) needs to be configured to handle decimals or something?  Or maybe there's a better data type than "Number" (though Access doesn't seem to get into Floats and Doubles and all that)?  I've googled around and haven't found much on the subject; there were lots of similar questions but nothing that really matched this situation.  So as always, any clues would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub ExportReport()
    Call connect("M:\Matrix\5-Information Technology\1-Knowledge Base\Reporting\Agent Stats.accdb") 'This just connects to the DB and works fine.

    Dim test As String, i As Integer
    Range("A3").Select
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
        test = "INSERT INTO [My Report] " & _
            "([CALL DATE], [CAMPAIGN], [AVG AGENTS], " & _
            "[OFFERED], [ANSWERED], [HANDLE(M)], [AVG HANDLE(M)], " & _
            "[TALK(M)], [AVG TALK(M)], [DISPO(M)], " & _
            "[ABANDONED], [ABAN PCT], [ASA(S)], " & _
            "[SVC LVL PCT], [OUTBOUND], [OUTBOUND(M)], " & _
            "[OVERFLOW], [OVERFLOW(M)]) " & _
        "VALUES('" & _
            ActiveCell.Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value & "', '" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value & "', '" _
            & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value & "');"

        DB.Execute test
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next i

    Call CloseDatabase  'Again, this part works fine
End Sub
```

Comment: What I would do: `Debug.Print test`. Now look what the concatenated SQL-Statement really contains. I suspect: The decimal separators are not as expected. Are they?

Comment: Yes, it is what we'd expect (for example 5892.25).  I had tried the same idea with MsgBox (same result) but as an aside thanks for showing me Debug.Print.  I've been writing VBA macros for a few years now but I've never seen that before (lol).

Comment: If you show the Access table in Design View what Field Size is then shown for the Number fields? It have to be Single, Double or Decimal. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-the-field-size-HA010274716.aspx#BM2

Comment: That took care of it!  Sure enough, it was set to Long.  Thanks!  I'm still kind of a noob on Stack Overflow... how do I give you a +1 and mark this question as solved?  :)

Comment: You can accept my answer. Questions with accepted answers are solved.

Answer (score 1):

There mainly are two reasons for that with SQL INSERT statement decimal digits get lost.

First: The database field has not the correct size for decimal digits.

Second: The decimal separators in the INSERT statement are different from the database decimal separator.

In Access, you can control the field size of the numeric fields in design view. For values with decimal digits it must be Single, Double or Decimal. See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-the-field-size-HA010274716.aspx#BM2

The second possibility mainly occurs, if there are different locale settings between the system that generates the INSERT statements and the system that hosts the database. As result of the comments in the question, this was not the case in this case.

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to this issue, I don't understand adodb devs haven't thought about it.

In your vba, shift decimals to integers using 10,100... Then upload the data and divide by the shifting factor inside access using an existing query or from excel but it will be slower accessing the db another time

Comment: The answer is not really helpful. Choosing the correct datatype in the database solves the problem, as mentions in the comment of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to solve this but with a little workaround.

From VBA, look for the greatest number of digits in the column(s) you want to export to your database. Let say you have these numbers, 1.034; 2.42 ; 4.2311 . So the number will be 4.

Bring that to a power number, 10,000

In VBA, multiply all the number in each column you want to export with the power number, that will be 1,034 ; 2,420, 42,311

Export the data with only full round numbers

Then before the VBA sub ends, run an update query on the numeric columns with decimals and divide all the values by 10,000 or run it from within the database with a dedicated query or stored procedure.

I made a quick youtube on this

Pascal

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZS4Z0I50EU

http://bricabrac.tekcities.com

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com